# Select older dependency build on Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

When you run new build with dependency, you can select dependency-build on "Dependencies" tab via a dropdown. But the dropdown shows only 20 last builds. How can I select older builds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an internal property that you can override in TeamCity

`teamcity.runCustomBuild.buildsLimit`

You can probably override this in the UI as a configuration parameter

[image]

otherwise you may have to add this to the internal.properties file on the physical server. To find the path for this you can navigate to Administration > Diagnostics > Internal Properties or append this to your server root (admin/admin.html?item=diagnostics&tab=properties)

This will give you the path to the properties file

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way to select dependency by providing given build number instead of selecting option from dropdown?

Comment: FYI doesn't work as a build config (at least not in 2019.1.3) but does work in `internal.properties`,  and takes effect without restart.

Comment: Whether we should give in the dependency build project or at the building project? I have tried giving in both places but didn't work. Can any help here?